# Is there a way to create a webpage/ program that gets information from other websites and then does some calculations with it?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to create a webpage/ program that gets information from other websites and then does some calculations with it? for example: Website ABC displays information of this week's weather. Is there a way for my webpage to extract the information from weather.com(generic name) of every day and calculate the average?

Comment: Yes. There is a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is an API. https://openweathermap.org/api for example, you can pull that and run calculations on the data you get from there.

Most API's have limits so it's a good idea to cache some data serverside if possible, but for practice you should be fine just doing a GET on an api endpoint.

Comment: If I'm trying to code a stock screener. Is there a way to write a program that would sift through the info on morningstar or another financial site, and display all the stocks that are priced over xyz

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but often times not easy. If the site you are trying to get data from has some sort of API it is very easy, unfortunately very few sites offer these. Without an api your tactics can vary depending on the site. These can include

- Web Scraping - Download the webpage and "scrape" data out of it
- Reverse engineering - Figure out where they got their info and fetch it from the original source
- Reverse engineering #2 - If the site is a single page app you can reverse engineer the front end app to make the same api calls

Unfortunately all of these approaches except for using an API can be pretty error prone since each time the external site updates there is the potential for it to break your application.

If you can get access to an api things get much easier and pretty much all apis have documentation giving details on how to use them

Comment: If I'm trying to code a stock screener. Is there a way to write a program that would sift through the info on morningstar or another financial site, and display all the stocks that are priced over xyz

Comment: Your best bet would be to look for an API which give you the stocks info. I know they exist but I believe they aren't free

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to research about web crawlers. And the other suggestion is look into the webpage that you are looking for information, maybe there is a API that you can use in order to do it.

Follow this Example API
https://openweathermap.org/api

Answer (score 0):

You could use a web crawler to scrape the site:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler

Also check this out:

http://blog.gainlo.co/index.php/2016/06/29/build-web-crawler/